# Persist in database PendingIntent extracted from within a Notification

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-database, notification-listener

Right now I have an app which is capturing all the notifications sent by other apps using the [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService).

I managed to persist in a database the title, date, etc, but I wonder what's the best way to persist the PendingIntent that can be acquired with:

```
override fun onNotificationPosted(statusBarNotification: StatusBarNotification) {
    val pendingIntent = statusBarNotification.notification.contentIntent
}
```

My goal is to be able to persist that intent in a database in a way that I can later retrieve all notifications and when the user clicks in any of it then the original intent is fired.

Comment: This isn't possible. I don't understand why you need to persist the `PendingIntent`. Please explain.

Comment: @DavidWasser I am creating a notification history app, in which I save all the notification data in a database so later I can show to the user a list of notifications received, including a click action to trigger the initial pending intent; that's why I need that.

Comment: Yeah, this is not possible. If the `PendingIntent` no longer exists then you cannot reproduce it. `PendingIntent`s contain transient data. They aren't persistent over reboots and they can be deleted, modified or replaced by the applications that created them. What you are trying to do is not possible, nor is it of any value to users. Sorry.